# Issue with scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

I am having issues with my custom scrollbar code. It works on my [biography page](http://babywitch.altervista.org/Writing/SLITD/testing/biography.html) but does not work on my [relations page](http://babywitch.altervista.org/Writing/SLITD/testing/relations.html).

The JavaScript codes are uploaded to my server in two different files. I didn't touch the code so I am not really sure why it is not working.

```js
/*! Copyright (c) 2011 Piotr Rochala (http://rocha.la)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
 * and GPL (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php) licenses.
 *
 * Version: 1.0.6
 *
 */
(function(d){jQuery.fn.extend({slimScroll:function(m){var a=d.extend({wheelStep:20,width:"auto",height:"250px",size:"7px",color:"#000",position:"right",distance:"1px",start:"top",opacity:0.4,alwaysVisible:!1,disableFadeOut:!1,railVisible:!1,railColor:"#333",railOpacity:"0.2",railClass:"slimScrollRail",barClass:"slimScrollBar",wrapperClass:"slimScrollDiv",allowPageScroll:!1,scroll:0,touchScrollStep:200},m);this.each(function(){function f(h,d,f){var g=h,e=b.outerHeight()-c.outerHeight();d&&(g=parseInt(c.css("top"))+
h*parseInt(a.wheelStep)/100*c.outerHeight(),g=Math.min(Math.max(g,0),e),c.css({top:g+"px"}));j=parseInt(c.css("top"))/(b.outerHeight()-c.outerHeight());g=j*(b[0].scrollHeight-b.outerHeight());f&&(g=h,h=g/b[0].scrollHeight*b.outerHeight(),h=Math.min(Math.max(h,0),e),c.css({top:h+"px"}));b.scrollTop(g);q();l()}function r(){s=Math.max(b.outerHeight()/b[0].scrollHeight*b.outerHeight(),A);c.css({height:s+"px"})}function q(){r();clearTimeout(w);j==~~j&&(n=a.allowPageScroll,x!=j&&b.trigger("slimscroll",
0==~~j?"top":"bottom"));x=j;s>=b.outerHeight()?n=!0:(c.stop(!0,!0).fadeIn("fast"),a.railVisible&&e.stop(!0,!0).fadeIn("fast"))}function l(){a.alwaysVisible||(w=setTimeout(function(){if((!a.disableFadeOut||!p)&&!t&&!u)c.fadeOut("slow"),e.fadeOut("slow")},1E3))}var p,t,u,w,y,s,j,x,A=30,n=!1,b=d(this);if(b.parent().hasClass("slimScrollDiv")){var k=b.scrollTop(),c=b.parent().find(".slimScrollBar"),e=b.parent().find(".slimScrollRail");r();m&&("scrollTo"in m?k=parseInt(a.scrollTo):"scrollBy"in m&&(k+=parseInt(a.scrollBy)),
f(k,!1,!0))}else{a.height="auto"==a.height?b.parent().innerHeight():a.height;k=d("<div></div>").addClass(a.wrapperClass).css({position:"relative",overflow:"hidden",width:a.width,height:a.height});b.css({overflow:"hidden",width:a.width,height:a.height});var e=d("<div></div>").addClass(a.railClass).css({width:a.size,height:"100%",position:"absolute",top:0,display:a.alwaysVisible&&a.railVisible?"block":"none","border-radius":a.size,background:a.railColor,opacity:a.railOpacity,zIndex:90}),c=d("<div></div>").addClass(a.barClass).css({background:a.color,
width:a.size,position:"absolute",top:0,opacity:a.opacity,display:a.alwaysVisible?"block":"none","border-radius":a.size,BorderRadius:a.size,MozBorderRadius:a.size,WebkitBorderRadius:a.size,zIndex:99}),z="right"==a.position?{right:a.distance}:{left:a.distance};e.css(z);c.css(z);b.wrap(k);b.parent().append(c);b.parent().append(e);c.draggable({axis:"y",containment:"parent",start:function(){u=!0},stop:function(){u=!1;l()},drag:function(){f(0,d(this).position().top,!1)}});e.hover(function(){q()},function(){l()});
c.hover(function(){t=!0},function(){t=!1});b.hover(function(){p=!0;q();l()},function(){p=!1;l()});b.bind("touchstart",function(a){a.originalEvent.touches.length&&(y=a.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY)});b.bind("touchmove",function(b){b.originalEvent.preventDefault();b.originalEvent.touches.length&&f((y-b.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY)/a.touchScrollStep,!0)});var v=function(a){if(p){a=a||window.event;var b=0;a.wheelDelta&&(b=-a.wheelDelta/120);a.detail&&(b=a.detail/3);f(b,!0);a.preventDefault&&!n&&
a.preventDefault();n||(a.returnValue=!1)}};(function(){window.addEventListener?(this.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll",v,!1),this.addEventListener("mousewheel",v,!1)):document.attachEvent("onmousewheel",v)})();r();"bottom"==a.start?(c.css({top:b.outerHeight()-c.outerHeight()}),f(0,!0)):"object"==typeof a.start&&(f(d(a.start).position().top,null,!0),a.alwaysVisible||c.hide())}});return this}});jQuery.fn.extend({slimscroll:jQuery.fn.slimScroll})})(jQuery);







$(function(){
    $('#content').slimScroll({
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%',
  color: '#FFFFFFF',
  allowPageScroll: false, 
 });
});
```

```css
body{
font-family: Candara, Calibri, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 10px;
 font-style: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 20px;
    color:#9DC8E0;
    }
    
    h1{
    background-color: #C7DBE6;
    color: #707070;
    font-family: Candara, Calibri, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-style: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    }
    
    h2{
    border-bottom-style: dashed;
    border-bottom-color: #C7DBE6;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    font-size: 10px;
 font-style: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #BD9EC1;
    }
    
    b{
    color: #BD9EC1;
    font-size: 10px;
 font-style: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 20px;
     font-family: Candara, Calibri, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
    
    }
    
    i{
    color: #BD9EC1;
        font-size: 10px;
 
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 20px;
     font-family: Candara, Calibri, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
     }
     
     u{
     border-bottom-style: dashed;
    border-bottom-color: #C7DBE6;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    font-size: 10px;
 font-style: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #BD9EC1;
    }
    
    hr{
    border-bottom-style: double;
    border-bottom color: #C7DBE6;
    border-bottom-width: 3px;
    border-top-style: none;
    }
    
/* Comment actual layout */

.iconleft{
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
background:url('http://r27.imgfast.net/users/2716/29/35/50/avatars/9141-81.png');
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top:5px;
}

.bioleft{
width: 360px;
height: 120px;
background: transparent;
position: realtive;
overflow: auto;
margin-left: 130px;
}

.iconright{
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
background:url('http://r27.imgfast.net/users/2716/29/35/50/avatars/9141-81.png');
margin-left: 380px;
margin-top:5px;
}


.bioright{
width: 360px;
height: 120px;
background: transparent;
position: realtive;
overflow: auto;
margin-left: -360px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://babywitch.altervista.org/Writing/SLITD/testing/relationships.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://babywitch.altervista.org/Writing/SLITD/testing/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://babywitch.altervista.org/Writing/SLITD/testing/scroll.js"></script>
<div id="content">

<div class="iconleft">
<div class="bioleft">
<h1><center>Character Name</center></h1>
<h2><center>relationship</center></h2>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer at lorem posuere, sodales metus et, lobortis tortor. Pellentesque laoreet, ante at tempor maximus, elit ante aliquet justo, eget viverra velit augue dapibus lacus. Donec quis interdum lectus. Sed vel urna ut arcu vulputate viverra in eget eros. Suspendisse mollis nunc elit. Sed id ipsum sed urna bibendum porta. Integer scelerisque magna vitae molestie porttitor. Etiam tincidunt, mi nec posuere blandit, purus felis placerat urna, non suscipit elit ex nec orci. Quisque ullamcorper, ligula vitae posuere cursus, lorem magna posuere velit, et interdum lectus sem nec lacus. Mauris vel hendrerit mi. Phasellus vehicula metus nunc, vel blandit lacus cursus id. Vivamus sit amet tincidunt purus, in tristique nisi. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam posuere consequat ex, quis dictum erat. Vestibulum in feugiat quam.
</div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="iconright">
<div class="bioright">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer at lorem posuere, sodales metus et, lobortis tortor. Pellentesque laoreet, ante at tempor maximus, elit ante aliquet justo, eget viverra velit augue dapibus lacus. Donec quis interdum lectus. Sed vel urna ut arcu vulputate viverra in eget eros. Suspendisse mollis nunc elit. Sed id ipsum sed urna bibendum porta. Integer scelerisque magna vitae molestie porttitor. Etiam tincidunt, mi nec posuere blandit, purus felis placerat urna, non suscipit elit ex nec orci. Quisque ullamcorper, ligula vitae posuere cursus, lorem magna posuere velit, et interdum lectus sem nec lacus. Mauris vel hendrerit mi. Phasellus vehicula metus nunc, vel blandit lacus cursus id. Vivamus sit amet tincidunt purus, in tristique nisi. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam posuere consequat ex, quis dictum erat. Vestibulum in feugiat quam.
</div></div>

<br>
<div class="iconleft">
<div class="bioleft">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer at lorem posuere, sodales metus et, lobortis tortor. Pellentesque laoreet, ante at tempor maximus, elit ante aliquet justo, eget viverra velit augue dapibus lacus. Donec quis interdum lectus. Sed vel urna ut arcu vulputate viverra in eget eros. Suspendisse mollis nunc elit. Sed id ipsum sed urna bibendum porta. Integer scelerisque magna vitae molestie porttitor. Etiam tincidunt, mi nec posuere blandit, purus felis placerat urna, non suscipit elit ex nec orci. Quisque ullamcorper, ligula vitae posuere cursus, lorem magna posuere velit, et interdum lectus sem nec lacus. Mauris vel hendrerit mi. Phasellus vehicula metus nunc, vel blandit lacus cursus id. Vivamus sit amet tincidunt purus, in tristique nisi. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam posuere consequat ex, quis dictum erat. Vestibulum in feugiat quam.
</div>
</div>



</div>
```

Comment: I suggest you use common settings of browsers instead of using your custom scroll bar, according to UX design, it would have a bad effect specially when it is hidden!

Answer (score 0):

i think you use in your relationships.css line no. 88
.bioleft{overflow:auto;}

Answer (score 0):

```js
/*! Copyright (c) 2011 Piotr Rochala (http://rocha.la)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
 * and GPL (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php) licenses.
 *
 * Version: 1.0.6
 *
 */
(function(d){jQuery.fn.extend({slimScroll:function(m){var a=d.extend({wheelStep:20,width:"auto",height:"250px",size:"7px",color:"#000",position:"right",distance:"1px",start:"top",opacity:0.4,alwaysVisible:!1,disableFadeOut:!1,railVisible:!1,railColor:"#333",railOpacity:"0.2",railClass:"slimScrollRail",barClass:"slimScrollBar",wrapperClass:"slimScrollDiv",allowPageScroll:!1,scroll:0,touchScrollStep:200},m);this.each(function(){function f(h,d,f){var g=h,e=b.outerHeight()-c.outerHeight();d&&(g=parseInt(c.css("top"))+
h*parseInt(a.wheelStep)/100*c.outerHeight(),g=Math.min(Math.max(g,0),e),c.css({top:g+"px"}));j=parseInt(c.css("top"))/(b.outerHeight()-c.outerHeight());g=j*(b[0].scrollHeight-b.outerHeight());f&&(g=h,h=g/b[0].scrollHeight*b.outerHeight(),h=Math.min(Math.max(h,0),e),c.css({top:h+"px"}));b.scrollTop(g);q();l()}function r(){s=Math.max(b.outerHeight()/b[0].scrollHeight*b.outerHeight(),A);c.css({height:s+"px"})}function q(){r();clearTimeout(w);j==~~j&&(n=a.allowPageScroll,x!=j&&b.trigger("slimscroll",
0==~~j?"top":"bottom"));x=j;s>=b.outerHeight()?n=!0:(c.stop(!0,!0).fadeIn("fast"),a.railVisible&&e.stop(!0,!0).fadeIn("fast"))}function l(){a.alwaysVisible||(w=setTimeout(function(){if((!a.disableFadeOut||!p)&&!t&&!u)c.fadeOut("slow"),e.fadeOut("slow")},1E3))}var p,t,u,w,y,s,j,x,A=30,n=!1,b=d(this);if(b.parent().hasClass("slimScrollDiv")){var k=b.scrollTop(),c=b.parent().find(".slimScrollBar"),e=b.parent().find(".slimScrollRail");r();m&&("scrollTo"in m?k=parseInt(a.scrollTo):"scrollBy"in m&&(k+=parseInt(a.scrollBy)),
f(k,!1,!0))}else{a.height="auto"==a.height?b.parent().innerHeight():a.height;k=d("<div></div>").addClass(a.wrapperClass).css({position:"relative",overflow:"hidden",width:a.width,height:a.height});b.css({overflow:"hidden",width:a.width,height:a.height});var e=d("<div></div>").addClass(a.railClass).css({width:a.size,height:"100%",position:"absolute",top:0,display:a.alwaysVisible&&a.railVisible?"block":"none","border-radius":a.size,background:a.railColor,opacity:a.railOpacity,zIndex:90}),c=d("<div></div>").addClass(a.barClass).css({background:a.color,
width:a.size,position:"absolute",top:0,opacity:a.opacity,display:a.alwaysVisible?"block":"none","border-radius":a.size,BorderRadius:a.size,MozBorderRadius:a.size,WebkitBorderRadius:a.size,zIndex:99}),z="right"==a.position?{right:a.distance}:{left:a.distance};e.css(z);c.css(z);b.wrap(k);b.parent().append(c);b.parent().append(e);c.draggable({axis:"y",containment:"parent",start:function(){u=!0},stop:function(){u=!1;l()},drag:function(){f(0,d(this).position().top,!1)}});e.hover(function(){q()},function(){l()});
c.hover(function(){t=!0},function(){t=!1});b.hover(function(){p=!0;q();l()},function(){p=!1;l()});b.bind("touchstart",function(a){a.originalEvent.touches.length&&(y=a.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY)});b.bind("touchmove",function(b){b.originalEvent.preventDefault();b.originalEvent.touches.length&&f((y-b.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY)/a.touchScrollStep,!0)});var v=function(a){if(p){a=a||window.event;var b=0;a.wheelDelta&&(b=-a.wheelDelta/120);a.detail&&(b=a.detail/3);f(b,!0);a.preventDefault&&!n&&
a.preventDefault();n||(a.returnValue=!1)}};(function(){window.addEventListener?(this.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll",v,!1),this.addEventListener("mousewheel",v,!1)):document.attachEvent("onmousewheel",v)})();r();"bottom"==a.start?(c.css({top:b.outerHeight()-c.outerHeight()}),f(0,!0)):"object"==typeof a.start&&(f(d(a.start).position().top,null,!0),a.alwaysVisible||c.hide())}});return this}});jQuery.fn.extend({slimscroll:jQuery.fn.slimScroll})})(jQuery);







$(function(){
    $('#content').slimScroll({
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%',
  color: '#FFFFFFF',
  allowPageScroll: false, 
 });
});
```

```css
body{
font-family: Candara, Calibri, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 10px;
 font-style: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 20px;
    color:#9DC8E0;
    }
    
    h1{
    background-color: #C7DBE6;
    color: #707070;
    font-family: Candara, Calibri, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-style: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    }
    
    h2{
    border-bottom-style: dashed;
    border-bottom-color: #C7DBE6;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    font-size: 10px;
 font-style: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #BD9EC1;
    }
    
    b{
    color: #BD9EC1;
    font-size: 10px;
 font-style: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 20px;
     font-family: Candara, Calibri, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
    
    }
    
    i{
    color: #BD9EC1;
        font-size: 10px;
 
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 20px;
     font-family: Candara, Calibri, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
     }
     
     u{
     border-bottom-style: dashed;
    border-bottom-color: #C7DBE6;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    font-size: 10px;
 font-style: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #BD9EC1;
    }
    
    hr{
    border-bottom-style: double;
    border-bottom color: #C7DBE6;
    border-bottom-width: 3px;
    border-top-style: none;
    }
    
/* Comment actual layout */

.iconleft{
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
background:url('http://r27.imgfast.net/users/2716/29/35/50/avatars/9141-81.png');
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top:5px;
}

.bioleft{
width: 360px;
height: 120px;
background: transparent;
position: realtive;
overflow: auto;
margin-left: 130px;
}

.iconright{
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
background:url('http://r27.imgfast.net/users/2716/29/35/50/avatars/9141-81.png');
margin-left: 380px;
margin-top:5px;
}


.bioright{
width: 360px;
height: 120px;
background: transparent;
position: realtive;
overflow: auto;
margin-left: -360px;
}
.bioleft{overflow:auto !important;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://babywitch.altervista.org/Writing/SLITD/testing/relationships.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://babywitch.altervista.org/Writing/SLITD/testing/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://babywitch.altervista.org/Writing/SLITD/testing/scroll.js"></script>


<div id="content">

<div class="iconleft">
<div class="bioleft">
<h1><center>Character Name</center></h1>
<h2><center>relationship</center></h2>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer at lorem posuere, sodales metus et, lobortis tortor. Pellentesque laoreet, ante at tempor maximus, elit ante aliquet justo, eget viverra velit augue dapibus lacus. Donec quis interdum lectus. Sed vel urna ut arcu vulputate viverra in eget eros. Suspendisse mollis nunc elit. Sed id ipsum sed urna bibendum porta. Integer scelerisque magna vitae molestie porttitor. Etiam tincidunt, mi nec posuere blandit, purus felis placerat urna, non suscipit elit ex nec orci. Quisque ullamcorper, ligula vitae posuere cursus, lorem magna posuere velit, et interdum lectus sem nec lacus. Mauris vel hendrerit mi. Phasellus vehicula metus nunc, vel blandit lacus cursus id. Vivamus sit amet tincidunt purus, in tristique nisi. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam posuere consequat ex, quis dictum erat. Vestibulum in feugiat quam.
</div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="iconright">
<div class="bioright">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer at lorem posuere, sodales metus et, lobortis tortor. Pellentesque laoreet, ante at tempor maximus, elit ante aliquet justo, eget viverra velit augue dapibus lacus. Donec quis interdum lectus. Sed vel urna ut arcu vulputate viverra in eget eros. Suspendisse mollis nunc elit. Sed id ipsum sed urna bibendum porta. Integer scelerisque magna vitae molestie porttitor. Etiam tincidunt, mi nec posuere blandit, purus felis placerat urna, non suscipit elit ex nec orci. Quisque ullamcorper, ligula vitae posuere cursus, lorem magna posuere velit, et interdum lectus sem nec lacus. Mauris vel hendrerit mi. Phasellus vehicula metus nunc, vel blandit lacus cursus id. Vivamus sit amet tincidunt purus, in tristique nisi. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam posuere consequat ex, quis dictum erat. Vestibulum in feugiat quam.
</div></div>

<br>
<div class="iconleft">
<div class="bioleft">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer at lorem posuere, sodales metus et, lobortis tortor. Pellentesque laoreet, ante at tempor maximus, elit ante aliquet justo, eget viverra velit augue dapibus lacus. Donec quis interdum lectus. Sed vel urna ut arcu vulputate viverra in eget eros. Suspendisse mollis nunc elit. Sed id ipsum sed urna bibendum porta. Integer scelerisque magna vitae molestie porttitor. Etiam tincidunt, mi nec posuere blandit, purus felis placerat urna, non suscipit elit ex nec orci. Quisque ullamcorper, ligula vitae posuere cursus, lorem magna posuere velit, et interdum lectus sem nec lacus. Mauris vel hendrerit mi. Phasellus vehicula metus nunc, vel blandit lacus cursus id. Vivamus sit amet tincidunt purus, in tristique nisi. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam posuere consequat ex, quis dictum erat. Vestibulum in feugiat quam.
</div>
</div>



</div>
```